# Segmentation fault with dynamic memory allocation (2D array) in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, 2d, allocation

This is actually a continued problem. Firstly, the idea was to append a matrix from a 1D array. Now I want it to be purely 2D. Like the first time, I'm having some problems with a segmentation fault, and I'm not sure where the problem is because I don't know how to use 2D arrays correctly. The program crashes with the following code. I've been fiddling around with it, but can't get it to work properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROWS 10
#define COLUMNS 10

void fillMatrix (int *matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS], int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j= 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        }
    }
}
void printMatrix (int *matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS], int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j= 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
void sumMatrix (int *matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS], int *matrixA[ROWS][COLUMNS], int *matrixB[ROWS][COLUMNS], int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j= 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = *matrixA[i][j] + *matrixB[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS], r, s, i;
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    do{
    printf("Rows and columns (min 1 1, max 10 10) ");
    scanf("%d %d", &r, &s);
    }while(r > ROWS || r < 1 || s > COLUMNS || s < 1);

    int** matrixA;
    matrixA=(int**)malloc(r*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0; i<r; i++)
        matrixA[i]=(int*)malloc(s*sizeof(int));

    printf("\nMatrix A:\n\n");
    fillMatrix(matrixA, r, s);
    printMatrix(matrixA, r, s);

    int** matrixB;
    matrixB=(int**)malloc(r*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0; i<r; i++)
        matrixB[i]=(int*)malloc(s*sizeof(int));

    printf("\nMatrix B:\n\n");
    fillMatrix(matrixB, r, s);
    printMatrix(matrixB, r, s);

    int** matrixC;
    matrixC=(int**)malloc(r*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0; i<r; i++)
        matrixC[i]=(int*)malloc(s*sizeof(int));

    printf("\nSummed up (Matrix C):\n\n");
    sumMatrix(matrixC, matrixA, matrixB, r, s);
    printMatrix(matrixC, r, s);

    free(matrixA);
    free(matrixB);
    free(matrixC);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. What compiler version are you using?

Comment: Please reduce your code to the relevant parts, where you're having problems.

Comment: Should be `int matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS]` and likewise for `matrixA` and `matrixB`. The `int *` makes it a 2D array of pointers to `int`.

Comment: What do you mean 'reduce the code'? I'm having a problem with the whole thing. Am I even declaring the 2D array properly? I'm new to C, I don't see a reason someone would downvote the question. It does compile for me, though. It fails to execute the code because of a pointer mistake, but I can't really locate it.

Comment: @lurker This does fix the problem a little bit, still it crashes because of something I wrongly declared in the alloc. Any idea?

Comment: Expression is incorrect as well: `matrix[i][j] = *matrixA[i][j] + *matrixB[i][j];` should be `matrix[i][j] = matrixA[i][j] + matrixB[i][j];`. Finally, I would make the arguments to the functions `int **matrix` rather than `int matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS]`.

Comment: @lurker That is exactly it. Seems I just didn't know how to declare them. Your approach works flawlessly. Why didn't you submit it as an answer so I can mark it as answered. Thank you very much!

Comment: Human beat me to writing it as an answer. That's cool. Glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `time.h` to the top and declare the function parameters as a pointer to a pointer and it should work.

Right now you have a triple pointer (a 2d array of pointers). Change it to `int ** matrix` for all similar parameters.

Similarly, remove all prepended asterisks from matrix operations inside your function:

`matrix[i][j] = *matrixA[i][j] + *matrixB[i][j];`

should be

`matrix[i][j] = matrixA[i][j] + matrixB[i][j];`

I removed brackets so the answer isn't excessively long, you probably should keep them in your code.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ROWS 10
#define COLUMNS 10

void fillMatrix (int **matrix, int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for(j= 0; j < columns; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
}

void printMatrix (int **matrix, int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j= 0; j < columns; j++)
            printf("%2d ", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

void sumMatrix (int **matrix, int **matrixA, int **matrixB, int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = matrixA[i][j] + matrixB[i][j];
}

int main()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what @lurker said and I implemented it already. Thank you for your input though, I understand where the errors were now.